# How to parse and create JSON tuples with php

Tags: php, json, highcharts, tuples

I'm trying to create php-representations of Highcharts series in php+orm implementing the [JsonSerializable Interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) and then json_encode them into javascript in the view.

However the gradient for the [fillColor](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.fillColor) uses a tuples array, which doesn't seem to have an equivalent in php, namely:

```
{stops: [
            [0, "rgba(40, 96, 144, 0.35)"],
            [1, "rgba(40, 96, 144, 0.0)"]
        ]
}
```

When I try to load this with json_decode I get an error JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX.

Is there some way to create the above json with json_encode in PHP or some alternative solution that would work with highcharts fillColor gradient.

Comment: `stops` should be in quotes, otherwise it's not JSON. How was this generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
    "stops": [
        [0, "rgba(40, 96, 144, 0.35)"],
        [1, "rgba(40, 96, 144, 0.0)"]
    ]
}
```

This is a valid json, the one you posted above isn't. *stops* should be in double quotes.

I use this link to validate my json when i am in doubt or can't figure where the problem is, you can try it :

[Json Validator](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: you are right. I was so focused on the tuples that I didn't notice the double quotes on the stops.